# Matlab to calculate a spectral line parameter for each layer

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate a parameter defined as `x`,( this is defined in my code below) for the given spectral lines in each layer. My atmospheric profile has `10` layers. I know how to calculate x for just one layer. Then I get `5` values for `x` corresponding to each spectral line ( or wavelength) . 
Suppose I want to do this for all `10` layers. Then my output should have `10` rows and `5` columns , size should be `(10,5)` , `10` represent number of the layer and `5` represent the spectral line. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

```
wl=[100 200 300 400 500]; %5 wavelengths, 5 spectral lines 
br=[0.12 0.56 0.45 0.67 0.89]; % broadening parameter for each wavelength


p=[1 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 ];    % pressure for 10 layers

T=[101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110];   % temperature for 10 layers

%suppose I want to caculate a parameter, x for all the layers
% x is defined as,( wavelength*br*T)/p
%when I do the calculation for the first layer,I have to consider all the
%wavelengths , all the broadening parameters and only the first value of
%pressure and only the first value of temperature 


 for i=1:5;
     x(i)= (wl(i)*br(i)*T(1))/p(1);
 end
% x is the x parameter for all the wavelengths in the first layer
%Now I want to calculate the x parameter for all the wavelengths in all 10 
%layers
%my output should have 10 rows for 10 layers and  5 columns , size= (10,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need loops for this case

```
>> (T./p)'*(wl.*br)

ans =

   1.0e+05 *

    0.0121    0.1131    0.1364    0.2707    0.4495
    0.0136    0.1269    0.1530    0.3037    0.5043
    0.0155    0.1442    0.1738    0.3451    0.5729
    0.0178    0.1664    0.2006    0.3982    0.6611
    0.0210    0.1960    0.2362    0.4690    0.7788
    0.0254    0.2374    0.2862    0.5682    0.9434
    0.0321    0.2996    0.3611    0.7169    1.1904
    0.0432    0.4032    0.4860    0.9648    1.6020
    0.0654    0.6104    0.7358    1.4606    2.4253
    0.1320    1.2320    1.4850    2.9480    4.8950
```